# Inserting rows from the streaming tables into one table in realtime

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I have two tables say DOG and FISH.
Table DOG has columns

```
name|species-name|neighbourhood
```

Table FISH has columns

```
name|species-name|water-type
```

In both of the tables data is streaming in realtime. I want to add the data from each of the table to a new table Animals in realtime having columns.

```
name|species-name|neighbourhood|water-type
```

For eg:-
for dog table two rows are streamed ie

```
yxz, shephard, london
abc, poodle, NYC
```

for fish table two rows are streamed ie

```
lkj, Tuna, saltwater
ghf, Cod, freshwater
```

I want data of both these table into animal table like

```
name|species-name|neighbourhood|water-type
----+------------+-------------+----------
yxz  shephard     london
abc  poodle       NYC
lkj  Tuna                       saltwater
ghf  Cod                        freshwater
------------------------------------------
```

i have used materialzied view for one table, but i cant seem to get my head around how can i use it for two table join.

Comment: Why can't you use 2 mat.views? One for DOGS table and other one for FISH table

Comment: I have used table dogs and fish for easier understanding, in actual dogs and fish table are two events table having more than 30 rows each but many of the columns are common. We dont want to deal with join on fly between two tables, as the logic is complex. that is why we are thinking of adding rows from both table into one for easier aggregation and filter. The table will cater to thousands of unique qeury every second. Hope you understand.

Comment: I still can't understand your problem. You're talking about "join", but you want just "union". Create table with all the columns and 2 materialize views which should insert to this table from "dogs" and "cats"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand you want to union two data streams into one table.

You can just create materialized view for each of the tables (`dogs` and `fish`)

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW fish_mt TO animal AS
SELECT `name`, `species-name`, `water-type` FROM fish;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW dogs_mt TO animal AS
SELECT `name`, `species-name`, `neighbourhood` FROM dogs;
```

Your result table (`animal`) should contain the columns from both of the source tables.

---

If you want to change the schema of result table (`animal`) dynamically, I guess there is no straight way to do it now (version 21.12).
But soon support for semi-structured JSON data will be added, you can look there. https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/pull/22535

Comment: This worked. Marked it as accepted answer. If not for this answer i would have gone aws lambda way to union data of two data stream. Thanks!!